# How to format Json output

Tags: json, eclipselink, moxy

Please help me how to get JSON output as below:

```
{
   "_costMethod": "Average",
   "fundingDate": 2008-10-02,
   "fundingAmount": 2510959.95
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
   "@type": "sma",
   "costMethod": "Average",
   "fundingDate": "2008-10-02",
   "fundingAmount": "2510959.95"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417758/is-there-a-possibility-to-hide-the-type-entry-when-marshalling-subclasses-to?rq=1

Comment: Could you add details about your object model?  Then I can help you remove the inheritance indicator.

Comment: @Blender I'm not sure it's a pure duplicate.  The question also wants to change the variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output from your question, you are currently not using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s native JSON binding.  The following should help.

**Java Model**

Below is my best guess at your object model based on your post.  I have added the metadata necessary to get the output that you are looking for.

- The `@XmlElement` annotation can be used to change the name of a key.
- I have used the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to control the format of the `Date` property.

```
package forum14047050;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(propOrder={"costMethod", "fundingDate", "fundingAmount"})
public class Sma {

    private String costMethod;
    private Date fundingDate;
    private double fundingAmount;

    @XmlElement(name="_costMethod")
    public String getCostMethod() {
        return costMethod;
    }

    public void setCostMethod(String costMethod) {
        this.costMethod = costMethod;
    }

    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    public Date getFundingDate() {
        return fundingDate;
    }

    public void setFundingDate(Date fundingDate) {
        this.fundingDate = fundingDate;
    }

    public double getFundingAmount() {
        return fundingAmount;
    }

    public void setFundingAmount(double fundingAmount) {
        this.fundingAmount = fundingAmount;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo Code**

```java
package forum14047050;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Sma.class}, properties);

        Sma sma = new Sma();
        sma.setCostMethod("Average");
        sma.setFundingDate(new Date(108, 9, 2));
        sma.setFundingAmount(2510959.95);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(sma, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Unlike your question I have quotes around the date value.  This is required to make it valid JSON.

```
{
   "_costMethod" : "Average",
   "fundingDate" : "2008-10-02",
   "fundingAmount" : 2510959.95
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html