# Controlling JSON output format

Tags: json, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

A reverse to the question asked at [How to format Json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047050/how-to-format-json-output/) ...

EclipseLink makes JSON output code from JAXB objects like this:

```
{
   "test" : {
      "count" : 10,
      "text" : "Craig"
   }
}
```

How do I make it put quotes around the number?
Thanks!

Comment: In JSON numbers are not wrapped in quotes, so why would you do it? If you need it, make use another type

Comment: Import in seems to need it.